# Older OpenCV 1.1 with newer Intel Integrated Performance Primitives (IPP) 7.1

Tags: opencv, image-processing, intel-ipp

I am having some trouble getting OpenCV 1.1 to load Intel's Integrated Performance Primitives (IPP) version 7.1.

My old Open CV 1.1 code was originally used with IPP 6.1 on another old Windows XP machine. For unimportant reasons, I now would like to use it on a fresh Windows 7 machine with [Intel's IPP 7.1](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp) which comes as part of [Intel Composer XE 2013](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-composer-xe). Intel's documentation [suggests that I have to change three lines in cxswitcher.c](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-open-source-computer-vision-library-opencv-faq/#3) to have the old OpenCV code find the new Intel IPP, namely I should update these lines:

```
static const char* ipp_sfx_ia32[] = { "-6.1", "-6.0", "-5.3", "-5.2", "-5.1", "", 0 };
static const char* ipp_sfx_ia64[] = { "64-6.1", "64-6.0", "64-5.3", "64-5.2", "64-5.1", "64", 0 };
static const char* ipp_sfx_em64t[] = { "em64t-6.1", "em64t-6.0", "em64t-5.3", "em64t-5.2", "em64t-5.1", "em64t", 0 };
```

which I have done so such that they now contain strings with the version number "7.1" as best as I could match the pattern:

```
static const char* ipp_sfx_ia32[] = { "-7.1", "-6.1", "-6.0", "-5.3", "-5.2", "-5.1", "", 0 };
static const char* ipp_sfx_ia64[] = {"64-7.1", "64-6.1", "64-6.0", "64-5.3", "64-5.2", "64-5.1", "64", 0 };
static const char* ipp_sfx_em64t[] = { "em64t-7.1","em64t-6.1", "em64t-6.0", "em64t-5.3", "em64t-5.2", "em64t-5.1", "em64t", 0 };
```

I have recompiled and also added the following directories to my path:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2013\redist\intel64\ipp`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2013\redist\intel32\ipp`

However when I run the sample code containing the `cvGetModuleInfo()` function, my code is unable to load the IPP dlls and I get this output:

```
     NumUploadedFunction = 0

     opencv_lib = cxcore: 1.1.0,
     add_modules =
```

�
Note that I have done some other tests. Intel's IPP demo's located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2013\ipp\demo\intel64` were able to run only after I added the directory with the DLL's to the path, so this makes me think that my PATH settings are correct. I also confirmed that this directory was in fact added to the path in my MSYS command prompt by running `echo $PATH` from within the MSYS prompt.

I suspect the problem is with the code in `cxswitcher.c`.

What else should I try?